# javascript array is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. I am not sure why  the myData array is empty in console.log as inputValue and inputName are not null and I can see them in log

```
var myData = new Array();

        $("#myelement :input").each(function(){

             var inputValue = $(this).val();             
            var inputName = $(this).attr('id');
             console.log(inputValue, inputName);
             myData.push=inputName;
             myData.push=inputValue;
             console.log(myData);
        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't right:

```
myData.push=inputName;
myData.push=inputValue
```

Basically, you are setting the `push` property of the array to a value.  But the `push` property of an array is already set to something, the function that adds an item to the array.

You want to call the `push` method instead, not replace it:

```
myData.push(inputName);
myData.push(inputValue);
```

Comment: Been a long day :) didn't even realize I was doing that :)